# Cannot distinguish file from folder

Tags: stat

I am trying to list all the files contained in a directory UROP by using `stat()`. However, the directory does not contain only files, but also folders, which I want to search too. Therefore, I am using recursion to access the folders whose files I want to be listed.

However, the `if` conditions in my loop do not manage to distinguish a file from a directory, and all files appear as directories; the result is an infinite recursion The code is the following. Thank you in advance!

```
using namespace std;

bool analysis(const char dirn[],ofstream& outfile)
{
    cout<<"New analysis;"<<endl;
    struct stat s;
    struct dirent *drnt = NULL;
    DIR *dir=NULL;

    dir=opendir(dirn);
    while(drnt = readdir(dir)){
        stat(drnt->d_name,&s);
        if(s.st_mode&S_IFDIR){
            if(analysis(drnt->d_name,outfile))
            {
                cout<<"Entered directory;"<<endl;
            }
        }
        if(s.st_mode&S_IFREG){
            cout<<"entered condition;"<<endl;
            cout<<drnt->d_name<<endl;
        }

    }
    return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `if(s.st_mode&S_IFDIR)` and `if(s.st_mode&S_IFREG)`,
try `if (S_ISDIR(s.st_mode))` and `if (S_ISREG(s.st_mode))`.

Comment: Before the S_ISDIR macro came up, the common use was `if ((s.st_mode & S_IFMT) == S_IFDIR) ...`.